# Show that $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2n+1} (\frac{j}{v})^{2n+1} < (\frac{j}{v})^3$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, power-series, taylor-expansion

How can I show that 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{2n+1} (\frac{j}{v})^{2n+1} < (\frac{j}{v})^3$$

given that $1\le j < v/3$. 
The  author suggests to use a geometric series with ratio $1/3$, but I am not sure how this helps. I would appreciate if you give some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a geometric series with $a_1= \frac {2}{3} \times (\frac{j}{v})^3$ and $q=\frac{1}{3}$. Then $\frac{2}{2n+1} (\frac{j}{v})^{2n+1} =\frac{2}{2n+1}\times (\frac{j}{v})^3 \times (\frac{j}{v})^{2(n-1)}< \frac{2}{3} \times (\frac{j}{v})^3 \times (\frac{1}{3})^{2n-2}  < a_1q^{n-1} =(\frac{2}{3^n})\times (\frac{j}{v})^3$.

Comment: Could you explain how to get the inequality?

Comment: @shk910 just edited.